# Numbering on chapters for Koma scrbook not working

Tags: numbering, koma-script, chapters

In the output the chapters are not numbered and the sections restart from 1 every time. The section links in the TOC always go to the first chapter, even in later chapters. I also get this output ion the log:

```
(./chapter3.tex
chapter without number
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{section.0.1})
has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

I have reviewed the tex file for a couple of hours trying to find where I went wrong, but I am still unable to find the problem.

This is the main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt, leqno, fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}        
\geometry{letterpaper}    
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitV, linkcolor=blue, 
            citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{warning}{Warning}

\def\grad{ \mbox{grad}}
\def\curl{ \mbox{curl}}
\def\div{ \mbox{div}}
\def\U{\ensuremath {\cal U}}
\def\S{\ensuremath {\cal S}}
\def\V{\ensuremath {\cal V}}
\def\R{\ensuremath {\cal R}}
\def\tr{\ensuremath {\mbox{tr}}}

% ------------------- Title and Author -----------------------------
\title{XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\subtitle{xxxxxxxxx}
\author{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
\end
```

and this is a sample chapter, the problem is in all chapters and in the TOC

```
% Activate the following line by filling in the right side. If for example the name of the root file is Main.tex, write
% "...root = Main.tex" if the chapter file is in the same directory, and "...root = ../Main.tex" if the chapter is in a subdirectory.
 
%!TEX root = main.tex  

\chapter{XXXXXXXXXXXX}
xxxxxxxxxx

\section{XXXXXXXX}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot `\mainmatter` after `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: you are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `scrbook` chapters are not numbered in the `\frontmatter`. In your code you are missing the explicit `\mainmatter` declaration, which should go in place of your `\pagenumbering{arabic}` (`\mainmatter` does that too).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\title{My Work}
\author{Me Myself}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter % < --- HERE !!

\chapter{chapter1}
\chapter{chapter2}
\chapter{chapter3}
\chapter{chapter4}
\chapter{chapter5}
\chapter{chapter6}

\end{document}
```